# How to handle the response JSON that is combination of array and object collection of JsonObjectRequest in Android Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am absolute beginner to Android. Now I start learning volley for HTTP requests and responses. I am binding the response data to the Listview. I am making the http get request like this.

This is my activity class with volley request

```
public class VolleyActivity extends Activity{
    private int lastSawFirstListItem;
    private int itemLoadedOn;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.volley_main);

        Button getBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_get_request);
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.volleyListView);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,new Entity[0]);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                List<Entity> items = new ArrayList<Entity>();
                try{
                    jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("feed");
                    //Then how to handle my response collection here
                     //because this is the combination of array and object collection
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"JSON exception",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext()).add(jsonRequest);
}

  public Entity convertToEntity(JSONObject item) throws JSONException
    {
        Entity en = new Entity();
        en.setId(item.getInt("id"));
        en.setName(item.getString("name"));
        en.setName(item.getString("url"));
        return en;
    }
}
```

This is the json link, I am requesting to http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json

How can I handle that combination? I already made ArrayRequest that throws error.

I am handling in the response callback like this

```
try{
                    jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("feed");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonObject.length();i++){
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(i);
                        String name = jsonObject.getJSONObject(sb.toString()).getString("name");
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

But it is throwing JSONException like in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please post the error.
The Volley request queue could also be made into a singleton instance.
You can use Gson to deserialise based on a POJO.

Comment: This ObjectRequest is not throwing error . I just wanna know how to iterate through and handle. Cause i have never done this.

Comment: ArrayRequest is throwing the json result array as error message.

Comment: So post that specific exception, it helps other users to investigate your issue.
What data is coming down? Could you provide the JSON schema or JSON data?

Comment: http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json

Comment: Use this [website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and put the JSON feed and build POJO objects.
Add the Gson gradle dependency.
Use this [Adapter](https://gist.github.com/ficusk/5474673) for your volley request, obviously making a subclass of it and your response will now come back as an Object modeled by the JSON feed instead of plain old JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. This is how I handled the json response that is the combination of objects and array in the response callback for my question.

```
List<Entity> items = new ArrayList<Entity>();
                try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feed");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       //work with entity items
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch strings from the jsonObject use
`String s = jsonObject.getString("sJson"); // here sJosn is the key in jsonObject.`
Similarly for Boolean use `Boolean b = jsonObject.getBoolean("key")` and for integers : `int i = jsonObject.getInt("keyint");`

Comment: Now I fetched like this. jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("feed") . So that will return array. So how can I loop through it. Then every item that is iterated through will be object. So how to retrieve its properties please ?

Comment: `this.jsonObject` is an array of jsonObjects right? 
you can simply use for loop to iterate. like `for (int i=0;i<this.jsonObject.length;i++){//create temporary jsonobjects and do the same as previous like tempJsonObject.getString("blah")}`

Comment: Where is the jsonException. This screenshot just shows the jsonObject

Comment: I used try catch statement. But it reached to catch block. But the error is json collection. So what is the issue ? Please how will you make a array of name of response object ?

Comment: can you please paste the complete relevant code here?